# php- How to detect MSISDN from headers?

Tags: php, header, msisdn

I am using getallheaders() function in php to check the users' headers.

I want to detect their MSISDN (phone number) when they are on mobile data, and I've found 'x-msisdn' header for the same. So here's my problem, if a person is using UC Browser (HandlerUI version) then I am getting  "x-msisdn" header but not on any other browsers like stock, Opera, UC browser (original version) etc.

How come UC browser handlerUI sets the "x-msisdn" header with every mobile operator but other browsers don't?

Answer (score 2):

Try these

```
    'X-MSISDN',
    'X_MSISDN',
    'HTTP-X-MSISDN',
    'X-UP-CALLING-LINE-ID',
    'X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID',
    'HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID',
    'X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN',
    'X-Forwarded-For',
    'Proxy-Client-IP',
    'WL-Proxy-Client-IP',
    'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'x-real-ip',
    'HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID',
    'HTTP_MSISDN',
    'MSISDN',
    'User-Identity-Forward-msisdn',
    'HTTP_X_MSISDN',
    'HTTP_X_NOKIA_MSISDN',
    'HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO',
```